# PHP Chmod Problem Creating files

Tags: php, file-get-contents, chmod, open-basedir

I've got the following situation:

public_html     - 755

=> avatar       - 777

=> poll         - 755

Now when I use the following code, i'll get an error (Warning: file_put_contents(../test.php) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in XXX):

```
<?php
file_put_contents('../test.php','<?php');
?>
```

But when I use the code below, it'll work just fine:

```
<?php
file_put_contents('test.php','<?php');
?>
```

(both executed from 'avatar', with 0777)

How can I solve this?

Comment: "both executed from 'avatar'"? How certain are you of this?

Comment: Yes, "execute.php" is in the avatar folder with permission 0777, but public_html has 0755 permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your script is executing from `avatar`, which has *0777* permission (world read/write/execute), it is normal that you are able to create a file within it (i.e.: `file_put_contents("test.php")`).

If you are not able to create files in `public_html` (i.e.: `file_put_contents("../test.php")`), it's because the user that is executing your script (most probably the Apache user) is not the owner of `public_html` (the owner is most probably a FTP user). Because *0755* means that only the owner is able to write to the directory, then others are only able to read or execute from it.

If you have shell access, you can use `chown` to change the owner of the file:

```
bash-4.1.5$ chown newuser public_html
```

Or you can `chmod` with higher permissions for non-owners, but you ought to be careful with that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not possible to write to a higher folder, even when you've 0777 permission.

It's not possible to use chmod on this dir, you'll have to use FTP or something.